# literate's replace option unable to deal with square brackets?

Tags: matlab-prettifier

I am using `matlab-pretifier` to add some Matlab code to an appendix, and I would like to replace the units [g/cm^3] in the matlab code by `$\mathrm{\left[g \cdot {cm}^{-3}\right]}$`. For that I use the literate option under `\lstinputlisting`. However, literate does not seem capable of reading the square brackets. I would appreciate some help to solve this..............

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[framed,numbered]{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
  language=Matlab,
  style=Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle=\mlttfamily\footnotesize,
  literate=
    {°}{\textdegree{}}1
    {ö}{{\"o}}1
    {é}{{\'e}}1
    {[g/cm^3]}{{$\mathrm{\left[g \cdot {cm}^{-3}\right]}$}}7
}

\lstinputlisting[]{matlab_code.m}

\end{document}
```

... and here the .m code:

```
% ----------------------------
% Rö and Mé (T = 23°C); Mass density [g/cm^3]
var_1 = 10;
```

Comment: Do you really want `cp1252`?

Comment: yes. With my current matlab version I can't save files with `utf8` encoding. For some reason I cannot recall right now, `cp1252` works a bit better for me than `latin1`, and this is why I'm using `cp1252`.